# Quantum Mechanics wave equation and energy states

Tags: probability, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quantum-mechanics

$ H =\begin{pmatrix} \alpha & \sqrt{\frac{3}{4}}\beta  \\ \sqrt{\frac{3}{4}}\beta    & \alpha+ \beta \end{pmatrix} $

1) Find the spectrum.

I have found this to be

$ E_{1} = -\frac{3}{4} \beta^{2} + \alpha $

$ E_{2} = \alpha +\beta - \frac{3}{4}\beta^{2} $

by solving $ det(H-EI)=0$

Not sure How to find the corresponding eigenvectors?

Also The second part, I am not sure how to start it.

Operator  $ Z = \zeta\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix} $

At Time t = 0 , Z is measured with outcome  $\zeta$

find $ | \psi(t) > $ for t>=0 and find the probabilities of measuring the possible outcomes for energy and Z as a function of time.

Comment: for the eigenvectors solve $(H-EI)|\psi\rangle=0$.

Comment: The usual method for finding an eigenvector $v=(v_1,v_2)^T$ is to note that $(H-EI)v=0$. This allows you to compute $v_2$ in terms of $v_1$, and then both are determined by $|v|^2=1$.

Comment: Do you mean something like this, $ H =\begin{pmatrix} \alpha & \sqrt{\frac{3}{4}}\beta  \\ \sqrt{\frac{3}{4}}\beta    & \alpha+ \beta \end{pmatrix} $ \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b  end{pmatrix} $  $= \begin{pmatrix} a & b \end{pmatrix}$